# Can not acces localhost:3000 ruby on rails ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, localhost

I have been trying to access or at least show my server in my Rails by running the command `rails s` or `rails server` and it does not work:

At first it told me I had to install new gems and to run the command `bundle install` to upgrade them and I did. It installed everything "correctly".

Now instead, I just get some usage help instead of Rails (for example commands I can use). I thought that Rails was out but I run the command `rails new myApp` and it does create me one and the bundle installs ok. I just want to start my app and try `localhost:port`, and that to open my app.

It happens the same when I try to generate something, for example `rails g model OneModel` (or `generate` instead of `g`) and for anything I want to generate. It seems it isn't understanding my commands.

I am noob new to ubuntu and far beyond that new to Rails and ruby. If you can help me I'd be so glad. Here's the output I get:

```
agustin@agustin:~/Agustin/myapp$ rails s
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                 # Default: /usr/bin/ruby
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
      [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git]               # Skip Git ignores and keeps
  -O, [--skip-active-record]     # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets]         # Skip Sprockets files
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]      # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                 # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]  # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                 # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev]                    # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge]                   # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]         # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--old-style-hash]         # Force using old style hash (:foo => 'bar') on Ruby >= 1.9

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
agustin@agustin:~/Agustin/myapp$
```

Comment: Are you trying to run an existing Rails application or to create a new one and run that?

Comment: What do you mean by "I thought that Rails was out" ?

Comment: I meant i thought it stopeed working. I already created a new app and i am trying to get it run by my browser in my port 3000, which i know its default. Any command besides new i type does not work, and throws me that...

Comment: @das-g i dont really know whats wrong with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run `rails s` from the project root directory.

eg, If you create a rails application, say `rails new my_app`, it will create a skeleton application `my_app` in the current directory. Now you have to `cd` to that directory to start the server

Comment: I did, as you can see its in the folder myapp

Comment: @Agustin - please type `ls` and share the result.

Comment: in any folder or in my app folder

Comment: @BroiSatse i think you want the ones in itallic which is ls insisde my app folder. Bold is for general but i dont think u need this

Comment: @Agustin Were you inside the `myapp` directory when running `rails s`? It'd only work in there.

Comment: @das-g yea i was, look in the code, it is there. Any operation i use with rails does not work

Comment: @das-g i run source ~/.bash_profile and now it tells me that gems are missing to run bundle install, i did and it and now it works. THANK YOU VERY MUCH im so glad